# Wizard Engine to build dynamic user-interface sequences

Tags: workflow, software-distribution

I'm looking for a way to combine different views (webviews) and map them in a wizard.

So as an example I have defined 4 views in a configuration:
(A, B, C and D)

Now I would like to enable a user to define the sequence via the user interface (or select different workflows with the same activity and different transitions) in a workflow engine:

- For example 1. User would like to have the sequence A-> C-> B-> D
- For example, 2nd user would like to have the sequence B-> C-> A-> D

Is there a software for .NET that can already do something like that?

The background is a manufacturing software which does many different thinks like quality control, work instructions, document management, ERP confirmations etc. And sometimes its necessary that the manufacturing software is executed in a right order (work flow).

The goal is that our customers can configure the views dynamically into workflows.

Answer (score 0):

I am investigated a couple of open source and commercial workflow engines developed by dot-net. I would like to recommend [Elsa Work-Flow Engine](https://elsa-workflows.github.io/elsa-core/), which is easy to use and well documented.
You can learn it and get skilled on it once and use almost in your all future projects.
good luck.

Comment: Think thats not the right tool. This is a workflow for process automation. I am looking for a workflow which defines a sequence of website pages which should be opened after another.